# Radio Button List: Buttons display above or below text, no in-line

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I am using Visual Studio 2013, and the radio button list is in Asp.Net.I want the text in line with the radio button instead of below the button.
[This is the output that i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfa6Q.png) But i want it to look like this [the output that i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4KjO.png)

here is the code

```
<div class="col-md-2">
 <asp:CheckBox ID="cbHalfDay" runat="server" Text="Half Day" AutoPostBack="true"  />
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblHalfday" runat="server" Visible="false" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"  >
      <asp:ListItem Text="First Half&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" Value ="1" />
      <asp:ListItem Text="Second Half" Value="2" />
     </asp:RadioButtonList>                               
 </div>
```